# firebase rules allow only certain user to write key valus

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

[image]

i want to write firebase realtime database rule where certain user can only write cetain key

ex: user with UID underlined in red can write value of key franchise_active only
user with UID underlined in green can write value of key vendor_active only

both users can read

Answer (score 0):

Sounds possible. Something like this should work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "application_status": {
      "$uid1": {
        "$uid2": {
          "franchise_active": {
            ".write": "auth.uid === $uid1"
          },
          "vendor_active": {
            ".write": "auth.uid === $uid2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```